# Regex Expression replacing spaces in both end of the word

Tags: javascript, regex

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/xaekh8op/13/

```
/(^|\s):bin:(\s|$)/gm
```

It is unable to scan and replace the one in the middle.
How can I fix that without repeating replace() twice.

Comment: Uhm, `str.replace(/\s?:bin:\s?/g, ':bin:');`

Comment: @adeneo that would make `text:bin:text` to work. therefore, `\s` was added.

Comment: I don't think you can have it both ways, you can't both match a space, and not match a space, I think you'd have to repeat the replace, once for before and start of string, and then once for after and end of string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `:bin: :bin: :bin:` there is only one space between the first two `:bin:` and your expression is not accepting that (either the space is used by the left side or by the right side).

A solution could be using

```
/\s*:bin:\s*/g
```

but this will match also `:bin::bin::bin:` and will replace all spaces around `:bin:`.

If you want at least a space, except at begin/end, then you could use

```
/(^|\s):bin:(?=$|\s)/g
```

Note that for the space after a "zero-width lookahead assertion" has been used so that the space is not consumed and can be considered for next match. Note however that this means that the space after will not be included in the replaced segment.

Comment: `/\s*:bin:\s*/g` this would break a lot things where `test:bin:` are not suppose to work. The second doesn't work as well.

Comment: @NubPro: sorry... typo: typed `(=?...)` instead of `(?=...)`

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```js
function custom() {
    var str = document.getElementById('original').innerHTML;
    var replacement = str.replace(/(^|\s+):bin:(\s+|$)|(:bin:)/gm, 'test');
    document.getElementById('replaced').innerHTML = replacement;
}

custom()
```

```html
<div id="original">:bin: abc :bin: 6666 :bin:</div>
<hr />
<div id="replaced"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Some times regex has problems that become complex, in these times using string functions such as contains, replace and substring is better.
Note that regex is not always a good option for getting data out of a string.